# Trying to store a previous value from a variable and then update, but it's just storing the current value? Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, timer

I'm trying to store the values of an array object (ao1) in another arraylist object (ao2), and then the values of ao1 is altered.

I want to then compare these values.

However, ao2 (which should have the old values) still ends up having the new values like ao1. To make this a bit more complicated, ao2 is being changed randomly through a timer class every 5 seconds. For a little bit of context, this is meant to simulate a stock market. For further complication, it is involving the use of Swing GUI.

Here is my code (I've added what I believe is relevant, in this case, ao1 would be "stockMarket" and ao2 would be "preStockMarket"):

### StockGUI Class

```
public StockGUI(){
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        displayCurrentStock(stockMarket, moveMarket);
                    }
                }, 0, 5000);

            setVisible(true);
}
```

### MarketMovement Class

```
private Random rn1 = new Random();
    //to determine whether to make the market move in a positive direction (1) or negative (0)
    private int rand1;

    private ArrayList<Stock> preStockList = new ArrayList();
    //create a timer so that I can replicate constant market movement
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

    public MarketMovement(Market market){

        getChangedMarket(market);
    }

    public void alterMarket(Market market){
        ArrayList<Stock> listOfStocks = market.getStockList();
        for (Stock stock : listOfStocks){
            rand1 = rn1.nextInt(2);

            if (rand1 == 1){
                market.pipUp(stock.getStockName().toString());
                System.out.println("current Stock is up " + stock.getStockName());
            }
            else {
                market.pipDown(stock.getStockName().toString());
                System.out.println("current Stock is down " + stock.getStockName());
            }
        }
    }
    public void storePreStock(Market market){
        for (Stock stock : market.getStockList()){
            preStockList.add(stock);
        }
    }
    public void getChangedMarket(Market stockMarket){
        //This timer allows me to run a randomiser constantly to determine which direction the market should move
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    storePreStock(stockMarket);
                    //rand1 = rn1.nextInt(2);
                    alterMarket(stockMarket);
                }
            }, 0, 5000);
    }
    public ArrayList<Stock> getPreStockList(){
        return preStockList;
    }
```

### Market Class

```
    private Stock stock1;
    private Stock stock2;
    private Stock stock3;

    private ArrayList<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList();

    int[] possibility = {0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3};
    private int rnd = new Random().nextInt(possibility.length);
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Market
     */
    public Market()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        stock1 = new Stock("GBP/USD", 1.2245, 1.2244);
        stock2 = new Stock("GBP/EUR", 1.3342, 1.3341);
        stock3 = new Stock("EUR/USD", 1.0224, 1.0223);
        stockList.add(stock1);
        stockList.add(stock2);
        stockList.add(stock3);

    }

    public void pipUp(String stockname){
                //Loop through each item in the ArrayList "stockList" and change its value based on the input created from MarketMovement.alterMarket()
        for (Stock stock : stockList){
            if (stock.getStockName().equals(stockname)){
                //change the increase value by a random number
                double currentBuy = stock.getBuy();
                double currentSell = stock.getSell();

                stock.setBuy(round(currentBuy + (0.0001*possibility[rnd]), 4));
                stock.setSell(round(currentSell + (0.0001*possibility[rnd]), 4));
            }
        }
    }

    public void pipDown(String stockname){
                for (Stock stock : stockList){
            if (stock.getStockName().equals(stockname)){
                //change the increase value by a random number
                double currentBuy = stock.getBuy();
                double currentSell = stock.getSell();

                stock.setBuy(round(currentBuy - (0.0001*possibility[rnd]), 4));
                stock.setSell(round(currentSell - (0.0001*possibility[rnd]), 4));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Perhaps when I assign the values from stockMarket to the preStockMarket variable, it is just referencing the address rather than the actual stored value, and therefore will always have the new values regardless?

Apologies, I'm still new to Java.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a `List` use the copy-constructor

```
List<Integer> oldList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
```

Comment: Didn't even know this existed! I think this has done the trick - thank you!